# Gradle on macOS Hight Sierra - Java 9

Tags: java, gradle, macos-sierra

I update java to the lasted version e then I following this guide to install grade using `Homebrew`:
[gradle installation guide](https://gradle.org/install/)

When the gradle installation is finished, I tried to launch gradre using the command: `grade` by command line but appear this error:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> * What went wrong:
> Could not determine java version from '9.0.1'.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Provide more information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a Gradle bug has been fixed in version `4.2.1`:

https://github.com/gradle/gradle/commit/d9c35cf9d74c102641fcfe0bb7bf622791a96caf